# Jersey Returning a 405 on a PUT

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am having issue with setting up and testing a REST call using embeded Jersey. I keep getting a 405 on a PUT request.

Here are some requests. I used all of the query parameters except one and it has a default value. These URL was generated by the Jersey WebResource in my test client.

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/hash/wes?hiddenDirs=false&hiddenFiles=false&id=3edf4867-1211-4ae7-a251-2af28ffac5a2&recursive=false&rehash=false&hashType=SHA1"

curl -i -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/hash/wes?hiddenDirs=false&hiddenFiles=false&id=3edf4867-1211-4ae7-a251-2af28ffac5a2&recursive=false&rehash=false"
```

Here is the basic response of the curl. It does not list PUT but using a OPTIONS request does list the PUT.

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(8.1.17.v20150415)
```

Here is the controller class. I use a lot of constants so the client and service are using the same values. You can see the translation in the output of OPTIONS below.

```
@Path(Constants.HASH_PATH) // "/hash"
public class HashController {
```

Here is the method I expect to handle the call.

```
@PUT
@Path(Constants.PATH_REST) // "{path : .*}" - I want this to accept directory paths.
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response hash(@PathParam("path") String path, @QueryParam(Constants.ID_PARAM) String id,
    @QueryParam(Constants.HASH_TYPE_PARAM) @DefaultValue(HashProcessor.DEFAULT_HASH_TYPE) String hashType,
    @QueryParam(Constants.HIDDEN_DIRS_PARAM) @DefaultValue("false") boolean hiddenDirectories,
    @QueryParam(Constants.HIDDEN_FILES_PARAM) @DefaultValue("false") boolean hiddenFiles,
    @QueryParam(Constants.RECURSIVE_PARAM) @DefaultValue("false") boolean recursive,
    @QueryParam(Constants.REHASH_PARAM) @DefaultValue("false") boolean reHashExisting) {
  Response ret = null;
```

I used an OPTIONS request to get the details of the contoller and see the PUT defined.

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost.corp.int:8080/hash > fileSync-hash.xml
```

Here is the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
  <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM" />
  <grammars>
    <include href="http://localhost:8080/application.wadl/xsd0.xsd">
      <doc title="Generated" xml:lang="en" />
    </include>
  </grammars>
  <resources base="http://localhost:8080/">
    <resource path="hash">
      <resource path="{path : .*}">
        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="path" style="template" type="xs:string" />
        <method id="hash" name="PUT">
          <request>
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:string" />
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="hashType" style="query" type="xs:string" default="SHA1" />
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="hiddenDirs" style="query" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="hiddenFiles" style="query" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="recursive" style="query" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="rehash" style="query" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
          </request>
          <response>
            <representation mediaType="application/json" />
          </response>
        </method>
      </resource>
      <resource path="{id : [\w\-]*}">
        <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="template" type="xs:string" />
        <method id="status" name="GET">
          <response>
            <representation mediaType="application/json" />
          </response>
        </method>
      </resource>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</application>
```

Here is the server output from the call.

```
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG nio:843 - created SCEP@6319a8b7{l(/10.20.67.195:56641)<->r(/10.20.67.71:8080),s=0,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG HttpParser:281 - filled 271/271
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG Server:365 - REQUEST /hash/wes on AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=3,c=0},r=1
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ContextHandler:942 - scope null||/hash/wes @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ContextHandler:1014 - context=||/hash/wes @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ServletHandler:415 - servlet ||/hash/wes -> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer-68e816f5
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ServletHandler:477 - chain=null
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG Server:367 - RESPONSE /hash/wes  405 handled=true
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG AsyncHttpConnection:211 - Enabled read interest SCEP@6319a8b7{l(/10.20.67.195:56641)<->r(/10.20.67.71:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=3,c=0},r=1}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:118 - ishut SCEP@6319a8b7{l(/10.20.67.195:56641)<->r(/10.20.67.71:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=-3},r=1}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG HttpParser:281 - filled -1/0
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG AsyncHttpConnection:145 - Disabled read interest while writing response SCEP@6319a8b7{l(/10.20.67.195:56641)<->r(/10.20.67.71:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=1}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG ChannelEndPoint:209 - close SCEP@6319a8b7{l(/10.20.67.195:56641)<->r(/10.20.67.71:8080),s=1,open=true,ishut=true,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=1}
2015-07-15 15:52:36 DEBUG nio:852 - destroyEndPoint SCEP@6319a8b7{l(null)<->r(0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080),s=0,open=false,ishut=true,oshut=true,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0!}-{AsyncHttpConnection@2993b935,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=0,c=-3},r=1}
```

I can make a GET call to the same controller. It returns a 404 as expected since the PUT failed but it is my code that is returning the 404 and not Jersey.

```
curl -i -X GET "http://dsk-107312:8080/hash/3edf4867-1211-4ae7-a251-2af28ffac5a2"
```

Here is some server output as Jersey configures itself in response to the first request. The GET would have failed too if Jersey had not discovered the controller.

```
Jul 15, 2015 3:46:13 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.wstrater.server.fileSync.server.handlers
Jul 15, 2015 3:46:13 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.wstrater.server.fileSync.server.handlers.FileController
  class com.wstrater.server.fileSync.server.handlers.HelloWorldController
  class com.wstrater.server.fileSync.server.handlers.HashController
  class com.wstrater.server.fileSync.server.handlers.DirectoryController
Jul 15, 2015 3:46:13 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Jul 15, 2015 3:46:14 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 03:25 AM'
```

I have used PUT successfully in other controllers so it must be something simple. In fact I was hoping I would stumble on it writing this post so often happens but not this time.

Thanks, Wes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes, Jersey (2.19) has a bug when running your routing example.
I tried this controller mimicking your example:

```
@Path("/hash")
public class HashController
{
    @PUT @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("{path: .+}")
    public String m1(@PathParam("path") String path) {
        return "m1 called with path " + path;
    }

    @GET @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("{path: [\\w\\-]+}")
    public String m2(@PathParam("path") String path) {
        return "m2 called with path " + path;
    }
}
```

When running CURL I get the same behaviour as your reported: GET request is fined, PUT returns a 405.

But when you use the same path template on both methods, (i.e. use either `@Path("{path: .+}")` or `@Path("{path: [\\w\\-]+}")` on both methods, everything works fine.

Good luck.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue. I guess Jersey does not like different regex patterns in the same controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The path "/hash/wes" matches both of your path schemes "/hash/{path : .*}" and "/hash/{id : [\w-]*}" and it seems that jersey chose the second controller method - which does support GET but not PUT.

EDIT: According to the [spec](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/spec/index.html#x3-340003.7.2%E2%80%9D) (3.7.2) this should not happen, so either my theory is false, or it is a bug in Jersey.

Comment: The `Method` should different between the two class methods. What I find interesting is that the list of `Allow` returned with the 405 does not list PUT but the WADL does.

Comment: Yes the method should make the difference. `Allow` returns GET which perfectly fits to the other controller method, therefore my original thought. Can't you allow 'PUT' method by your second controller method and see what happens?

Comment: I am not sure what else I can do to allow PUT and maybe that is what I am missing. I have the method annotated with PUT and an OPTIONS request does return the details on the PUT. I would be suspicious of the regex in the Path for the method but use that constant successfully in other controllers. I need the regex since I am trying to allow for a directory paths including sub-directories. The default behavior is to only return what is between the path separators and I want everything including the path separators.